# Reusing the same form for update and create or is there an easier method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In the profile page a user can write about himself that will then be displayed on the profile page. Now I don't want the user to submit multiple 'abouts' to the database. Once he has written it will be stored in the database and he should only be able to update the information. How will this be done exactly. What I've thought of now is to reuse the same form, if that is the only way how will that be done? I'm certain there is an easier way but cannot think of anything at the moment.

Comment: The profile page is where you show should show a form to a user. It can contain the fields prefilled or blank based on if the database has some value. Use a common template file say `_user_profile.blade.php`.

Comment: if I create a form for create(to submit the about to the database), I want to use the same form/about page to be able to update it again. If I understood your answer correctly. I only need to use the old helper to have the field prefilled and then the user just has to submit it again?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Hello new contributor!

Your question points to a lack of understanding of the basic workings of Laravel as a MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework.

The view layer (i.e form) only displays and collects information.

The controller validates that information and glues the application together.

The model stores the information.

In your case the "about" should be a single column in a table - no way for there to be more than one per user.
As far as the form goes, if you can reuse it, do it - code duplication is bad!

My suggestion would be to:

- read about MVC (there are many tutorials and courses online)
- [read the Laravel documentation in its entirety](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle)